# How to implement GridControl with CheckBox inside it in Syncfusion using C Sharp?

Tags: c#, syncfusion, gridcontrol

I want to implement `GridControl` for my project but I realize `Syncfusion GridControl` is little more tough than Windows controls.
my requirement is like that: Suppose I have three columns and 15 rows in my `gridControl` and in first column of first row I want to write some hardcoded input `string` and in second column of first row I want to add `CheckBox`.
Kindly suggest me how to bind cells with CheckBox so that it would work dynamically while scrolling.

I also go through from [Here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156420/how-to-bind-data-to-syncfusion-gridcontrol-in-c-sharp-using-windows-application)

Answer (score 0):

**Query 1**

In first column of first row I want to write some hardcoded input string
**Suggestion 1**

The cell value for a particular cell can be set by using CellValue property of cell style. Please refer the below code,

```
this.gridControl1[1, 1].CellValue = "Sample";
```

**Suggestion 2**

The cell value can also be set by using Text property of cell style. Please make use of below code,

```
this.gridControl1[2, 1].Text = "Data";
```

**Suggestion 3**

To set the cell value for a particular cell, the QueryCellInfo event can also be used. Please refer below code,

```
//Event Triggering
this.gridControl1.QueryCellInfo += GridControl_QueryCellInfo;
//Event Customization
private void GridControl_QueryCellInfo(object sender, GridQueryCellInfoEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.RowIndex==1 && e.ColIndex==1)
    {
        e.Style.CellValue = "Sample Name";
    }

    if(e.RowIndex==2 && e.ColIndex==1)
    {
        e.Style.Text = "Sample ID";
    }
}
```

**Query 2**

In second column of first row I want to add Checkbox

**Suggestion 1**

To set the cell type as CheckBox for a particular cell, the CellType property can be used and the name for the CheckBox can be set by using Description property. Please refer the below code,

```
this.gridControl1[1, 2].CellType = GridCellTypeName.CheckBox;
this.gridControl1[1, 2].Description = "CheckBox";
```

The CheckBox can be checked or unchecked based on the cell value by defining the CheckBoxOptions property of the cell.

```
this.gridControl1[1, 2].CheckBoxOptions =  new GridCheckBoxCellInfo("True","False","False",true);
this.gridControl1[1, 2].CellValue = "True";
```

**Suggestion 2**

To set Cell type as CheckBox for a particular cell, the QueryCellInfo event can also be used. Please refer the below code,

```
//Event Triggering
this.gridControl1.QueryCellInfo += GridControl_QueryCellInfo;
//Event Customization
private void GridControl_QueryCellInfo(object sender, GridQueryCellInfoEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.RowIndex==2 && e.ColIndex==2)
    {
        e.Style.CellType = GridCellTypeName.CheckBox;
        e.Style.Description = "CheckBox";
        e.Style.CheckBoxOptions.CheckedValue = "True";
        e.Style.CellValue="True";
    }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkYFj.png)

[Sample Link](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/174967/ze/CellStyles45019031)

[UG Link](https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/grid-control/cell-types#checkbox-cell-type)

Dashboard sample

\Syncfusion\EssentialStudio<Installed Version>\Windows\Grid.Windows\Samples\ Cell Types\Interactive Cell Demo\CS